# Python: Having trouble to terminate "while" loop under two consecutive condition

Tags: python, while-loop

I don't know what is the problem, but I can't end a while loop if it is under two if conditions. Let me show the code:

```
while True:
    k = input ("Please enter 'hello': ")
    if k == "hello":
        m = input ("Are your Sure? (Y/N): ")
        if m == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or "Yes":
            break
```

Now, after the second prompt, even if i type no or any other things, while loop still ends. I only want to end it after second confirmation. What is my mistake in the coding?

Comment: pls, properly indent your code.

Answer (score 5):

This is what internally happens.

**Your code:**

```
m == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or "Yes"
```

**Python Interpretation:**

```
(m == "Y" )or ("y" or "yes") or "Yes"
```

`("y" or "yes")` will always produce `y since it is not a falsey value` then `("y" or "yes") or "Yes"` is changed to this `"y" or "Yes"` again same value so finally `(m == "Y" )or ("y" or "yes") or "Yes"` is changed to `(m == "Y" )or "y"`

To avoid this you could use separate checking for all the condition or `in` as BenC stated

Or Even more simply

```
m.lower() in "yes" # Note that it also True if m is e or es or s etc..

      or

"yes".startwith(m.lower()) # This work perfectly as per my test cases
```

Comment: upvoted for `"yes".startwith(m.lower())` cool :)

Comment: @VivekSable thanks just thought of a different way to do it :P.

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

`if m == "Y" or m == "y" or m == "yes" or m == "Yes":`

Answer (score 1):

change `or` condition

**Demo**:

```
>>> while True:
...     k = raw_input ("Please enter 'hello': ")
...     if k == "hello":
...         m = raw_input ("Are your Sure? (Y/N): ")
...         if m == "Y" or m == "y" or m == "yes" or m == "Yes":
...             break
... 
Please enter 'hello': hello
Are your Sure? (Y/N): y
>>>
```

---

we can use `lower` string method to convert string to lower case,

**Demo**:

```
>>> m = raw_input ("Are your Sure? (Y/N): ").lower()
Are your Sure? (Y/N): Yes
>>> m
'yes'
```

---

**Note**:

Use raw_input() for Python 2.x

USe input() for Python 3.x